# Rails 4 - find in array field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have stored all user's roles in database field like this - roles: ["customer", "employee"]. This field has structure like array. I need select all employees.

Please, could you advise me, how to do that?

Comment: Try `User.where(roles: "%employee%")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.where(roles: "%employee%")
```